# Remove or skip the Initialisation process in Forge 1.7.10?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

In the new version of Forge (1.7.10) it spends time *"Initialising mods.."* etc. The problem is, this process is so *slow*. The 1.6.4 version was perfect! No loading bars or anything, just the Mojang logo and then you jumped into Minecraft.

My Macbook is a 2008 one and I can run Minecraft with no problems, but this new 1.7 forge is very annoying. It'd be ok if it happened only once, but every time I open it, it loads like it's installing the mods afresh.

Is there any way of configuring it so it can be more like version 1.6, or to skip the check/initialisation step (and thus remove the wait time)?

Answer (score 4):

There is no additional waiting. Before the game froze on the Mojang screen while it loaded all the mods. They updated it with the information so that you can see it is doing something.

The only thing that can be done to get mods to load faster is to ask each individual mod maker to make their mods load faster (which most of them could do by eliminating a lot of the logging they do during load.. but they wont ever do this cause when they get a crash error on loading these logs are what help them track it down).

Sorry you feel it is slower, this is just the way modding is in the latest versions of minecraft.

Answer (score 0):

In old versions of Forge the modloading process was almost exactly as it is now, with the main difference being that Forge now displays what step it is at in the debugging process. The init phase consists of two main parts for each mod, pre-initialization and initialization. There is no way to disable/skip these because without them most mods wouldn't work, the game would likely crash, or if you are lucky you just get hit by extremely heavy lag once you start your world and all the mods load then.

Pre-initialization is the phase where mods overwrite or add code to classes from other mods or the vanilla game code. This is used (sometimes) to add debugging code or (more often) to add compatibility fixes and extra features so that all the loaded mods can work together rather than conflict with each other. The setting up of preinit is actually rather fast, the slow part comes when other mods are loaded and the preinit scans all relevant classes, changing what needs to be changed for the mod to work.

Initialization is the bigger, bulkier phase where all the mods are actually loaded. This is where all the modifications the preinit phase set up are actually executed and injected into code from other mods during their loading. After the mods are fully loaded they do their background setup, often logging individual steps for debugging phrposes.